# Category filters not appearing in layered navigation

Tags: catalog, layered-navigation

Category filters are not appearing in Layered Navigation. I am not using any plugin for layered navigation. Attribute and Price filters are appearing.

I have set **Is Anchor** and **Show In Navigation** to YES for all the categories. I have read other answers on stackexchange as well. No idea why this is happening.

In **app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php** (Line 207)

`return $this->getChild('category_filter');` is returning **NULL**.

Comment: You are using a template maybe there are some problems with the xml files, check category.xml and your custom xml file for this template, block should be included here. You can also try to switch back to the default Package / Theme from Magento and see if the Cat filter appears.

Comment: Have you searched all layout files in `app/design` for `category_filter` to ensure they aren't removing the block?

Comment: thanks guys! I solved it. See the answer below. Thanks Cags, Marius and Samir :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks Cags! I did a whole search and found out, one of the xml files was removing the category_filter by the unsetChild method. Thanks a ton.

So the answer is, if you stumble upon such errors, do a full file search with the block name, and you will find the culprit "xml" file which may be removing the block forcefully.

In my case this happened:

```
<catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="catalog.leftnav">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>category_filter</name></action>
        </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```